# I want to have water flowing nicely out of the water tap

Tags: fluid-simulation

I am testing water flow out of a water tap.
But I only get water splashing out.
Any one knowing have to make/set the scene to have [water running out nicely](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrthL.jpg) as it does from a real water tap?
[image]

[image]

Comment: can you show us your inflow settings please?

Comment: if you want to solve your special problem (which might be other reasons like water colliding with your rigid body object) ...please provide your blend file. You can do this here: https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

just give your inflow some initial velocity like this:

[image]

so you get something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank, I changed the inflow vetocity from 4 to 1, but no change.
I also tried to disable the water tap in order to avoid collide problems there. But no change. Still splashing out.

How do I upload my blend file? don't see any attachment button.

[image: Settings for inflow]

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, it was the velocity settings. It was way to much with -4 on Z.
Changed it to 0, now it is running nicely out as it should.
Thank a lot.
I will post a picture later of the result of my test.